# Is it possible to add more information/functionality than just a title in a marker in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

Using the following line of code (with latlongVariable being coordinates for a location), I can add a marker to a map which will then produce a title of the location when clicked.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlongVariable).title("Marker Location Title"))
```

My question is, is it possible to add more than simply a title to the marker? For example, could I include a list view displaying more information about the location as well, maybe including a button that will send the user to another activity when clicked?

I've tried to research Android Google Map's onMapReady() method and it's functionality but I can't find the answers I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes you can check this library from github
https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy - one only has to listen to the `OnMarkerClickListener` and then show a custom `PopupWindow` above the marker. Some other guys here on StackOverflow suggested this solution and it actually looks quite good at first glance.

You can use `github` library as @Waleed Asim suggests for `interactiveInfoWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Just set InfoWindowAdapter to map and in getInfoContents inflate your custom layout.

mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

```
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
        return v;

    }
});
```